# The problem that data/suites.json is empty after receiving an Allure report

Tags: linux, jenkins-pipeline, allure

I would like to ask you for support about an error that I have not received before and have been dealing with for a long time.

I was showing the API tests I did in the Allure report. I didn't make any changes but now NaN comes as below:

[image]

Allure version: 2.8.x

The script I use: `steps.sh "allure generate ${ALLURE_RESULTS_API_FOLDER} -o ${ALLURE_REPORT_API_FOLDER}"`
The result folder is full, but I can't see the correct data when the report is generated:

[image]

[image]

I am waiting for my report outputs to arrive correctly.

When I do this manually, the report is generated.
This is a pipeline step running on jenkins line.